# Distribution function of parallel-connected system of k i.i.d exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Lets say that we have a parallel-connected array (system) of k independent components $T_1,T_2,...,T_k$ each having an exponentially distributed life length with parameter $\lambda$. The components are used such that each one is switched on immediately when the previous one fails so that the survival times add:

$T=T_1+T_2+...+T_k$

How can I find the distribution function $F_T(t)$ for the system?

Comment: The sum of i.i.d. exponential random variables is a [gamma random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with a certain shape and rate. Try iteratively applying the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of the exponential densities to arrive at this fact for yourself.

Comment: I am working with a task in R, and my original "guess" or intuition was that what you are saying is correct, so thank you for clearing this up! However, I am having trouble using the gamma distribution in my task (the gamma function in R to be specific). If $\lambda=4.7$, what would be the shape and rate of the gamma random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T_1, T_2, ... \sim^\mathrm{iid} \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, by which I mean *rate* $\lambda$, so *mean* $1/\lambda$, then $S_k := T_1 + \cdots + T_k \sim \Gamma(k, \lambda)$, ie *shape* $k$ and *rate* $\lambda$. You can see this stated [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#General) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#General).

You should try to prove this yourself. There will be countless proofs online that you can read, too.

Comment: Thank you! The explanation for the shape and rate made it all clear!